# Validating jwt token in router file

Tags: node.js, api, express, command-line-interface

I have created a Rest Api that performs some queries on a mysql database. The api is accesed through a cli a built with oclif. I am trying to validate a token though before the queries are executed. I want to do the validation in the same file (routes.js). This file looks like this:

```
module.exports = app => {
  const entry = require("../controlers/entry.controller.js");
  const sql = require("../models/db.js");
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  var express=require('express');

  // Retrieve a single Entry with Id
  var fs=require('fs');
  var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
  var jwt=require('express-jwt');
  app.use(
    jwt({
      secret: privateKey,
      credentialsRequired: false,
      getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
        if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
            return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
          return req.query.token;
        }
        return null;
      }
    }));


  app.get("/entry/:Id", entry.findOne);

  app.post("/energy/api/Login", function(req,res){ 
        var jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
        sql.query(`SELECT user,pass,quota,apikey,email FROM users WHERE user=?`,[req.query.username],(err,res1) => {
            //console.log(res1);
            const password=res1[0].pass;
            const e=res1[0].email;
            const a=res1[0].apikey;
            const q=res1[0].quota;
            const p=res1[0].privileges;
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.query.passw,password)){
                var jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
                var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
                var token = jwt.sign({user:req.query.user ,passw: req.query.passw,email: e, quota: q,apikey: a,privileges: p }, privateKey, { algorithm: 'HS256' });
                res.status(200).send(token);
            }
            else res.status(400).send("Bad Request");
        });

  });
```

In the login part, I create the token and return it to the CLI. Then the cli does something like this:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH']="Bearer " + token;
    await cli.anykey();
    //create new user
    if (`${flags.newuser}` !== "undefined" && `${flags.passw}` !== "undefined" && `${flags.email}` !== "undefined" && `${flags.quota}` !== "undefined" ){
            let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(`${flags.passw}`,10);
            await axios.post('https://localhost:8765/energy/api/Admin/users?username=' +`${flags.newuser}` +'&passw=' + hash +'&email=' + `${flags.email}`  +'&quota=' + `${flags.quota}`);

    }
```

However when the routes.js file gets the post command it handles it like this:

```
app.put("/energy/api/Admin/users/:username",async function(req,res){        
            if (req.params.username !== "undefined" && req.query.email !== "undefined" && req.query.quota !== "undefined"){ 
                console.log(req.params.username);
                sql.query(`UPDATE users SET pass=?,email=?,quota=? WHERE user=?`,[req.query.passw,req.query.email,req.query.quota,req.params.username],(err,res) => {
                            if (err) {
                              console.log("error: ", err);
                              result(err, null);
                              return;
                            }
            });
            }
            res.send("Successful");
  });
```

I want to add some middleware to validate the token, and also check if the parameter quota is >0 and if it is decrease it by one. How can I do this?

***Declaration***: This code is written in node.js,express.js

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code not modularized. 
And You have to write route middleware for protect the routes and not global middleware

I think this project will help you to understand the **jwt,express code**(https://github.com/ahari884/simple-node-boilerplate)
Please check it you will find the how to write jwt authentication for routes in express

Answer (score 0):

You can write a dedicated middlware like so:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

export async function verifyJWTToken(request, response, next) {
/*
* Normally JWTs are specified as Bearer Tokens.
* Authorization Header will have something like 'Bearer <token>' 
*/
  const header = request.headers.authorization;
  if (header && header.startsWith('Bearer ')) { tokens
    const token = header.slice(7, header.length);
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
    try {
      jwt.verify(token, secret);
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      next(new Error('Authentication Failed'));
    }
  } else {
    next(new Error('Missing Authentication Token'));
  }
}
```

You can then protect your routes by providing the middleware before your controller function:

```js
app.route('/users').get(verifyJWTToken, getUsers) //getUsers() is the controller function
```

Comment: but how would I check the parameters of the token?

Comment: jwt.verify() gives you the token details. You can save it to a const and then you can perform operations using the data.